# PHP $_GET method not working /Follow system

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

i am having a problem with the get method in php, i try to get a variable($profile_id) from one php page to another, the variable is working in this page

```
<?php
    $follow="";
    $loggedinid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $sqll = "SELECT id FROM Follow WHERE user_one='$loggedinid' AND user_two='$profile_id'"; 
  if($profile_id != $_SESSION["userid"]){
     $check= mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqll);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1){
        $follow='<a href="followaction.php?followaction=unfollow&profid=$profile_id">Unfollow</a>';//This is where i try to put the variable, so i can call it with the get method on followaction.php
      }else{
        $follow='<a href="followaction.php?followaction=follow&profid=$profile_id">Follow</a>';
      }
     }
?>
```

but then in the followaction.php when i call the profid, It returns $profile_id(sting) instead of the number it should be representing

```
<?php

include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");

$followaction=$_GET['followaction'];

$profileid = $_GET['profid'];

$loggedinid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$loggedinusername = $_SESSION['username'];

 if($followaction == 'follow'){
    mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO Follow VALUES('','$loggedinid','$profileid')");
}

if($followaction == 'unfollow'){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Follow WHERE user_one='$loggedinid' AND user_two='$profileid'";
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
}
?>
```

How can i fix this, everything is working but i cant transfer the profile_id to this page....

Comment: Your first script can't be working. You need to use " (double quotes) not single quotes or $profile_id will not be replaced

Comment: The first query Its working fine i have cheked it, the problem is not the querys the problem is getting the profile_id variablw to followaction.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work

```
 $follow='<a href="followaction.php?followaction=unfollow&profid=$profile_id">Unfollow</a>';
```

If you do

```
echo $follow;
```

You will get something like this (Notice $profile_id has not been replaced)

```
 <a href="followaction.php?followaction=unfollow&profid=$profile_id">Unfollow</a>
```

You need to use double quotes if you want variable replacement

```
 $follow="<a href=\"followaction.php?followaction=unfollow&profid=$profile_id\">Unfollow</a>";
```

Comment: THANKS!! Really apreciate it !